# Enable column menu in Kendo grid only for one column and hide specific columns by default on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to provide the column menu option for columns only in one specific column of the kendo grid. Also, when the page loads I want to display one specific columns and hide the other columns. The user can select the other(hidden) columns from the column menu option which is provided in one of the columns.

I have done something like this to hide the column menu from certain columns:

```
<body>
    <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                        ShipCountry: { type: "string" },
                                        ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                        ShipAddress: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 30,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        pageable: true,
                        columnMenu: true,
                        columns: [{
                            field: "OrderID",
                            title: "Order ID",
                            width: 120
                        }, {
                            field: "ShipCountry",
                            title: "Ship Country"
                        }, {
                            field: "ShipName",
                            title: "Ship Name"
                        }, {
                            field: "ShipAddress",
                            filterable: false
                        }
                        ]
                    });
                });
$(function(){
     $('#grid .k-header-column-menu').eq(0).hide();
     $('#grid .k-header-column-menu').eq(1).hide();
     $('#grid .k-header-column-menu').eq(2).hide();
})

            </script>
        </div>
</body>
```

Is there a better method to achieve these two functionalities?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar request, but I didn't put column-menu in one column rather I put it outside in toolbar section, additionally I added export buttons in same template.

```
var toolbarTemplate = '<div id="column-menu-button" style="float:left" ></div>';
var templ = '<div class="toolbar buttons-wrap" style="text-align: right;"><div id="toolbar"></div></div>';


var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: kendo.template(templ),
    columns: [
        {field: "name", menu: true, hidden: true},
        {field: "age", menu: false}
    ],
    sortable: true,
    dataSource: [
        {name: "Jane Doe", age: 30},
        {name: "John Doe", age: 33}
    ]
}).getKendoGrid();

var createKendoColumnMenu = function (id, dataSource, owner) {
    var kendoColumnMenu = $(id).kendoColumnMenu({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        filterable: false,
        sortable: false,
        columns: true,
        owner: owner,
    });
};

var createKendoToolBar = function (id) {
    var kendoToolBar = $(id).kendoToolBar().getKendoToolBar();

    return kendoToolBar;
};

createKendoToolBar('#toolbar').add({
    template: toolbarTemplate,
    id: 'column-menu',
    overflow: 'never'
});

createKendoColumnMenu('#column-menu-button', grid.dataSource, grid);
```

Check my example: [Custom toolbar](https://dojo.telerik.com/UsELovOz)

Comment: This method is working fine. But now I have discovered another issue. Whenever I'm using the hidden property in kendo grid column to hide certain columns by default, or whenever I'm applying certain filters on the grid from an external filter template, my grid column go out-of-order. That is, row data for each column shifts  right and it looks disorderd. I'm using remote data to populate my grid.

Answer (score 0):

Change your columns array to add the hidden property.

```
columns: [{
    field: "OrderID",
    title: "Order ID",
    width: 120,
    hidden: true
}, {
    field: "ShipCountry",
    title: "Ship Country",
    hidden: true
}, {
    field: "ShipName",
    title: "Ship Name",
    hidden: true
}, {
    field: "ShipAddress",
    filterable: false
}]
```

As far as the hiding the column menu. You already have the way to do it, as a function. It may be better to put it in the databound event of the grid, but the way you have it should work fine.

Comment: The hidden property is making my columns to go out of order. I'm populating the grid with remote data. The row data for the columns looks as if they are shifted to left, but the columns remain in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to enable the columnMenu option only in one column. Basically, I am adding a div element to the column headerTemplate in which I want to enable this feature. And then, I am attaching a kendoColumnMenu to it.
Here's an example: [ColumnMenu](https://dojo.telerik.com/UsELovOz/5)